How to add data for multiple objects in one row with sqlalchemy
I am performing a regular web scrape for laptop prices with Beautifulsoup. The data from these searches I want to put in a data base with Sqlalchemy. But for each search I want to add just one row, with the date of the search, and a new price for each of the 15 laptops (the laptop names are the names of the columns). I cannot figure out how to do this, your help is appreciated.
I want everything in 1 table so I can turn it into a csv and make some graphs of the data.
I have tried using a for loop, iterating over the names of the laptops that are in a dictionary (the values of the names are the url's that I use to get the price.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, sessionmaker, declarative_base

ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
USER_AGENT = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0")


def mediamarkt(url):
    headers = {
        "accept-language": ACCEPT_LANGUAGE,
        "user-agent": USER_AGENT,
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    laptop_page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(laptop_page, 'html.parser')

    price_list=[]
    item_prices = soup.select('span:-soup-contains("€")')
    for price in item_prices:
        price_list.append(price.text)
    try:
        laptop_price = int((price_list[-1].lstrip('€ ').rstrip('00').rstrip(',')))
        return laptop_price
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        return 0

def coolblue(url):
    headers = {
        "accept-language": ACCEPT_LANGUAGE,
        "user-agent": USER_AGENT,
    }
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    laptop_page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(laptop_page, 'html.parser')

    price_list = []
    item_prices = soup.find(class_ = 'sales-price__current js-sales-price-current')
    for price in item_prices:
        price_list.append(price.text)
    try:
        laptop_price = int((price_list[-1].rstrip(',-').replace('.','')))
        return laptop_price
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        return 0

now = datetime.datetime.now()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///laptop-prices.db', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

# dictionaries of all laptop names
laptop_names_mediamarkt = {}
laptop_names_coolblue = {}
laptop_names_mediamarkt.update({'MediamarktLenovoYogaPro714IRH8':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_lenovo-yoga-pro-7-14irh8-145-inch-intel-core-i7-32-gb-1-tb-1806227.html',
                                'MediamarktAcerSwift14SF1471T786Z':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_acer-swift-14-sf14-71t-786z-14-inch-intel-core-i7-32-gb-1-tb-1806717.html',
                                'MediamarktAcerAspire5Spin14A5SP1451MTN73H8':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_acer-aspire-5-spin-14-a5sp14-51mtn-73h8-14-inch-intel-core-i7-32-gb-1-tb-1790678.html',
                                'MediamarktMSICommercial14HA13MGvPRO098nl':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_msi-commercial-14-h-a13mg-vpro-098nl-14-inch-intel-core-i7-32-gb-1-tb-1868294.html',
                                'MediamarktLenovoYogaSlim7':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_lenovo-yoga-ultra-slim-7-14-inch-intel-core-ultra-7-32-gb-1-tb-1810315.html',
                                'MediamarktASUSZenbook14OledUX3405MAPP156W':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_asus-zenbook-14-oled-ux3405ma-pp156w-14-inch-intel-core-ultra-7-32-gb-1-tb-1811355.html',
                                'MediamarktHPPavillionPlus14ew1045nd':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_hp-pavilion-plus-14-ew1045nd-14-inch-intel-core-ultra-7-32-gb-1-tb-1870542.html',
                                'MediamarktASUSZenbook14OledUX3405MAPP278W':'https://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_asus-zenbook-14-oled-ux3405ma-pp278w-14-inch-intel-core-ultra-9-32-gb-1-tb-1803492.html',
                                })
laptop_names_coolblue.update({'CoolblueASUSZenbook14OledUX3405MAPP278W':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/943557/asus-zenbook-14-oled-ux3405ma-pp278w.html',
                                'CoolblueLenovoIdeapadSlim5Oled14IMH983DA007BMH':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/948982/lenovo-ideapad-slim-5-oled-14imh9-83da007bmh.html',
                                'CoolblueLenovoIdeapadPro514APH883AM000DMH':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/926535/lenovo-ideapad-pro-5-14aph8-83am000dmh.html',
                                'CoolblueAcerSwiftGo14OledSFG147373FU':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/947157/acer-swift-go-14-oled-sfg14-73-73fu.html',
                                'CoolblueLenovoYogaPro714APH882Y8002TMH':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/933460/lenovo-yoga-pro-7-14aph8-82y8002tmh.html',
                                'CoolblueLenovoYogaSlim714IMH983CV0054MH':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/946460/lenovo-yoga-slim-7-14imh9-83cv0054mh.html',
                                'CoolblueHPPavillionPlus14ew1970nd':'https://www.coolblue.nl/product/947519/hp-pavilion-plus-oled-14-ew1970nd.html'
                                })

class Laptops(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'laptop_prices'
    search_date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=False, primary_key=True)
    MediamarktLenovoYogaPro714IRH8: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    MediamarktAcerSwift14SF1471T786Z: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False, nullable=True)
    MediamarktAcerAspire5Spin14A5SP1451MTN73H8: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    MediamarktMSICommercial14HA13MGvPRO098nl: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    MediamarktLenovoYogaSlim7: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    MediamarktASUSZenbook14OledUX3405MAPP156W: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    MediamarktHPPavillionPlus14ew1045nd: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    MediamarktASUSZenbook14OledUX3405MAPP278W: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueASUSZenbook14OledUX3405MAPP278W: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueLenovoIdeapadSlim5Oled14IMH983DA007BMH: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueLenovoIdeapadPro514APH883AM000DMH: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueAcerSwiftGo14OledSFG147373FU: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueLenovoYogaPro714APH882Y8002TMH: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueLenovoYogaSlim714IMH983CV0054MH: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)
    CoolblueHPPavillionPlus14ew1970nd: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=False)


def daily_search():
    for laptop in laptop_names_mediamarkt:
        url = laptop_names_mediamarkt[laptop]
        daily_price = mediamarkt(url)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        new_price = Laptops(search_date=now, laptop=daily_price)

        with Session() as session:
            session.add(new_price)
            session.commit()


    for laptop in laptop_names_coolblue:
        url = laptop_names_coolblue[laptop]
        daily_price = coolblue(url)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        new_price = Laptops(search_date=now, laptop=daily_price)

        with Session() as session:
            session.add(new_price)
            session.commit()


daily_search()

But this returns the following error:
'TypeError: 'laptop' is an invalid keyword argument for Laptops'
How can I solve this?

Can you share your  Database model as well

I have added the entire code to my original question, hope that helps.

In the class Laptops you need to specify the columns that you want to insert in to.
It looks like You defined the schema with the Value of the tables itself.
here
new_price = Laptops(search_date=now, laptop=daily_price)
tries to insert columns search_date and laptop .But the Laptops schema only has the search_date field defined along with the unwanted values you provided (Laptop models).
Try this
    class Laptops(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'laptop_prices'
        search_date: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=False, primary_key=True)
        laptop: str


I did define the columns in the Laptop class, didn't I? It has 16 columns, one for the search date, and 15 for each type of laptop.
The 'new_price' should have inserted the new price in each of these columns, but apparently it does not work that way.
I have managed to solve this with sqlite, by manually referencing the columns and adding the price data. But I was hoping it could also be done with sqlalchemy.

you did define the columns other than the laptop column.
